# add element to ruby array return new array

Tags: ruby, arrays, copy, new-operator

I would like to add an element to an array but *without* actually changing that array and instead it returning a new one. In other words, I want to avoid:

```
arr = [1,2]
arr << 3
```

Which would return:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Changing arr itself. How can I avoid this and create a new array?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can easily add two arrays in Ruby with `plus` operator. So, just make an array out of your element.

```
arr = [1, 2]
puts arr + [3]
# => [1, 2, 3]
puts arr
# => [1, 2]
```

Comment: Why is there no way in ruby to add an item to an array with affecting the original array?

Comment: @gitb The array#+ method does this; it creates a new array from the left-hand side and the right-hand side of the plus operator and returns the new array, leaving both operands unmodified.

Answer (score 15):

it also works by extending arr using * operator

```
arr = [1,2]
puts [*arr, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: For those coming from JS or familiarized with it, this syntax is equivalent to the spread operator:

`
const arr = [1,2];
console.log([...arr, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
`